# SharePoint "Save this View" in doc library

Tags: document-library

If I login to my SharePoint site as site owner and filter documents in the document library, I can see the "Save this view" option. However, if I login as different user which has "Full control"access to the site, I don't see the save this view option. Do you know how to show this option for users who are not site owners? I edited the page and checked the webpart's miscellaneous option and found that "Disable 'Save This View' button" option is unchecked. Any idea why it's not showing for users who even have full control access?

Comment: can those users still create and save views normally? is it just the "save this view" button is missing? Also, when you are in the library as the user who cant see that option, have you already applied a filter? If no filter is applied and you are just looking at a standard view, then the option to "Save This View" won't show up because nothing has changed

Comment: Yes I applied filters. Users with full control access can't create views normally. Only site owners can create views. What am I missing? Why full control users can't create views?